# DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument on <body> element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I want to "catch" the very first moment when the `<body>` has created. I've tried using `DOMNodeInserted` / `DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument`. here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", handleDomInserted, true);
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument", handleDOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument, true);

function handleDOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
function handleDomInserted(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
</script> 
</head>

<body> 
<div id="foo">
  <span id="bazz"></span>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Why do those functions never get called?

Comment: Why not put the script tag with your actual code directly after the opening `<body>` tag? No need for event handlers.

Comment: I've made no real attempt to research this, but why would `DOMNodeInserted` fire when the relevant node(s) already exist within the source, when the DOM is being constructed? Does/should constructing the DOM from the HTML trigger a `DOMNodeInserted` event?

Comment: Just a note: DOM Mutation event are one the one hand deprecated and on the other hand their implementation tends do be buggy in the different browsers. [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is the replacement for it.

Comment: @David: Excellent point (I don't know the answer either). I would say they should not be triggered when the HTML is parsed, since no DOM manipulation methods are explicitly called.

Comment: @Felix: I'd consider asking the question, now; but I'm not even sure how to *phrase* it... (plus: no research undertaken, and Mutation Observers are deprecated, so I'm not sure it's even worth asking any more)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is correct but JavaScript events are NOT fired when the HTML is initially parsed by the browser. JS evens will only fire when DOM manipulation is done by JS.

E.g. if you add the following to the code sample, the event will fire:

```
<script>
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.innerHTML = 'test';
document.body.appendChild(d);
</script>
```

Comment: "JS evens will only fire when DOM manipulation is done by JS", makes sense.